# while debugging the application controller is going sytem class how stop this

Tags: java, eclipse

hi i am try to debugging my application for that i have put the break points at my code. while i try to run the application in a debugging mode the controller is unnecessary going into system class and checking the  below condition

```
 private static void checkKey(String key) {
        if (key == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("key can't be null");
        }
        if (key.equals("")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("key can't be empty");
        }
    }
```

how can i stop the controller is going into the system class
any help will appreciate.

Comment: How do you debug your application? Are you using eclipse? If you really debug "step by step" the debugger will step in every statement. You can skip those but it depends on the IDE you are using.

Comment: yes i am using eclipse.

Comment: Ok, are you familiar with the debug steps like step into, step over etc (see http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-stepping.htm)?

Comment: yah i know this but my doubt is why it is going inside system class and checking the above condition.

Comment: Which of the two conditions do you mean? Can you post a screenshot of the debugger stack?

Comment: in system class above checkKey(String key){} method here the controller is comming. but why it is comming.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever eclipse breaks on the debug point that you have put in your code:

1. Use `F8` key to jump to the next break-point.
2. If you want to execute one line of code at a time, use `F6` key. It will break on each line of your code. (Or use `Step Over` button available in debug mode)
3. If there is a method call and you want to go inside the method, use `F5` key and the control will go inside the method. (Or use `Step Into` button available in debug mode)

You might be using `Step Into` button or `F5` which is taking you to the corresponding method call which is a part of Java or other library.

Comment: no i know this basic function key's but my doubt is why it is going inside system class unnecessary and checking the above condition

Comment: Are you using `Step Into` button?

Comment: step into button means

Comment: Clicking that button will take you inside the method call present on the line. For example, if you have something like `someClass.someMethod()`, then pressing `F5` or `Step Into` will take the control inside `someMethod` method. And I am guessing this is the scenario you are facing now.